# Verilog syntax question

Tags: verilog

Something like this:

a=b?c:d ;
would make a=c, if b=1, 
else a would be made equal to d;

But what would doing the same thing on an array do?
Like this:

assign a = (|b[10:8])?8'hff : b[7:0];   // to limit the max value to 255
Does it check each of the 3 bits, 8, 9 & 10?

Comment: That will take the bit wise or of b[10], b[9], and b[8].  If any of those are 1 then you'll get 255 in a.  Otherwise you'll get b[7:0].  Is that what you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `a = ( | b[10:8] ) ? 8'hff : b[7:0];`

When `|` is used as a prefix, it is a [reduction operator](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/operators2.html). That means it operates on all the bits of the vector that follows it. So what's happening here is the bits of the vector b[10:8] are being or'ed together to get a single bit result.

That result is used to choose whether to assign the constant `8'hFF`, or the lower 8 bits of `b` to `a`.